# The two input fields are placing one over another instead of side by side or content like style

Tags: html, css

Here is my modal page which have background image on the background and two input fields(username, password) and two buttons(class name in code = .explore)(login and home).

But the text fields are getting placed one over another but i want content like style but unable to find sol. And even if mycode for button is right but it not showing the button on the modal page also.

```css
.ab {
              width: 320px;
              margin: 45px auto;
            }

    .ab hr.sep {
              background: #2196F3;
              box-shadow: none;
              border: none;
              height: 2px;
              width: 25%;
              margin: 0px auto 45px auto;
            }
     .ab .emoji {
              font-size: 1.2em;
            }

      .group {
              position: relative;
          display: contents;
          padding-top: 10px;
          margin: 45px 0;
            }


      input{

              background: none;
              color: #c6c6c6;
              font-size: 18px;
              padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
              display: block;
              width: 320px;
              border: none;
              border-radius: 0;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
            }
     input:focus,
     textarea:focus {
              outline: none;
            }
      input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label,
      textarea:focus ~ label,
     textarea:valid ~ label {
              top: -14px;
              font-size: 12px;
              color: orangered;
            }
     input:focus ~ .bar:before,
     textarea:focus ~ .bar:before {
              width: 320px;
            }

     input[type="password"] {
              letter-spacing: 0.3em;
            }

     label {
              color: #c6c6c6;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-weight: normal;
              position: absolute;
              pointer-events: none;
              left: 5px;
              top: 10px;
              -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
              transition: 300ms ease all;
            }

     .bar {
              position: relative;
              display: block;
              width: 320px;
            }
    .bar:before {
              content: '';
              height: 2px;
              width: 0;
              bottom: 0px;
              position: absolute;
              background: #2196F3;
              -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
              transition: 300ms ease all;
              left: 0%;
            }

        .explore {
              font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
              letter-spacing: 8px;
              background: none;
              color: floralwhite;
              position: absolute;
              outline: none;
              border: none;
              height: 50px;
              width: 190px;
              left: 50px;;
              font-size: 20px;
              z-index: 2;
              -webkit-transition: .01s .23s ease-out all;
              transition: .01s .23s ease-out all;
              overflow: hidden;
            margin: 30px;
            }
       .explore:before {
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              top: 0;
              height: 100%;
              width: 55%;
              background: #000000;
              z-index: -1;
              -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in all;
              transition: .3s ease-in all;
            }
        .explore:after {
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              left: -5%;
              top: 5%;
              height: 90%;
              width: 5%;
              background: white;
              z-index: -1;
              -webkit-transition: .4s .02s ease-in all;
              transition: .4s .02s ease-in all;
            }
         .explore:hover {
              cursor: pointer;
              color: transparent;
            }
        .explore:hover:before {
              left: 100%;
              width: 25%;
            }
        .explore:hover:after {
              left: 100%;
              width: 70%;
            }
        .explore:hover .icon-right.after:after {
              left: -80px;
              color: white;
              -webkit-transition: .2s .2s ease all;
              transition: .2s .2s ease all;
            }
        .explore:hover .icon-right.after:before {
              left: -104px;
              top: 14px;
              opacity: 0.2;
              color: white;
            }

        .icon-right {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              right: 0;
            }
        .icon-right:after {
              font-family: "FontAwesome";
              content: '\2192';
              font-size: 24px;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              top: 26px;
              -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, -50%, 0);
                      transform: translate3D(0, -50%, 0);
            }
        .icon-right.after:after {
              left: -250px;
              color: orangered;
              -webkit-transition: .15s .25s ease left, .5s .05s ease color;
              transition: .15s .25s ease left, .5s .05s ease color;
            }
        .icon-right.after:before {
              content: 'LogIN';
              position: absolute;
              left: -230px;
              top: 14px;
              opacity: 0;
              -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in all;
              transition: .2s ease-in all;
            }



.my_modal{
            display: none;      /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;    /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;         /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;        /* Full width */
            height: 100%;       /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;     /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }
        .modal-animated{
            background-image: url(maxresdefaultx.jpg);
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            margin:5% auto 15% auto;   /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
        }
.close{
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 0;
            color: aqua;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .close:hover,
        .close:focus{
             color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .image-container{                
            background-size: cover;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        image.avatar{
            width: 40%;
            border-radius: 60%;
            
        }
```

```html
 <div id= "id01" class="my_modal">
        <form class="modal-animated animate" action="actionpahe.php">
        <div class="image-container">
             <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="avatar-05.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            
        <div class="contents">
        <div class="ab">
    
   
            <hr class="sep"/>
            <div class="group">
            <input type="text" required="required"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Name</label>
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <input type="password" required="required"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Password</label>
            
            </div>
            

            <button class="explore">Login
                <span class="icon-right"></span>
                <span class="icon-right after"></span>
            </button>

             <button class="explore">Home
                <span class="icon-right"></span>
                <span class="icon-right after"></span>
             </button>
        
  </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the password textfield a different location than the username text field. Play around with the pixel value to see if that moves it to where you can see both text fields.

Try adding this in your CSS:

```
input[type="password"] { top: 20px; }
```